# What is the difference between MANUAL and MANUAL_IMMEDIATE in spring-kafka AckMode

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

From spring-docs, I can see

> **MANUAL** - the message listener is responsible to acknowledge() the Acknowledgment; after which, the same semantics as BATCH are applied.
>
> **MANUAL_IMMEDIATE** - commit the offset immediately when the Acknowledgment.acknowledge() method is called by the listener.

But what exactly is the difference if the listener is committing the offset. What additional steps are done for `MANUAL` mode

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MANUAL - acks are queued and the offsets committed in one operation when all the results from the last poll have been processed.

MANUAL_IMMEDIATE - the offset is committed immediately (sync or async) as long as the ack is performed on the listener thread.

Comment: So, in spring-kafka, it can make a difference for the batch mode - by comiting the offset of individual records ?

Comment: Not at all; the other way around; for a record listener, MANUAL commits the offsets at the end of the batch, MANUAL_IMMEDIATE commits them one-by-one.  There's little difference for a batch listener (just a minor timing difference because we still go through the queue).

Comment: However, with a batch listener and MANUAL_IMMEDIATE with syncCommits, you can catch the exception; with MANUAL, the error will send the batch to the error handler.